# Objects shrunk to their interface when sent to Angular

Tags: json, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a class Person and a class Business which both implements the interface User. When i create a List in C# all data fields for both persons and businesses are available, however when I pass that list to Angular only the datafields in User remains. Any ideas for how to fix this?

Classes:

```
interface User
 - int x;

class Person : User
 - int y;

class Business
 - int Z;
```

Method in api:

```
[HttpGet("users")]
public List<User> getAllUsers(){

  List<User> userList = new List<User>;
  
  ...code for adding persons and businesses to userList...

  return Ok(userList);
  
}
```

Angular request:

```
this.http.get("api/users")
.subscribe(result =>{
    console.log(result)
});
```

This returns a list of objects, but x (from interface) is the only datafield, not y or z from person and business.

I have debugged the Api and y or z are definitely stored in the list when getUser() returns userList. However they are not received by the frontend. My guess is Person and Business is shrunk down to User when serialized and sent to Angular.

It does however work when i change User to Object in getAllUsers(), but i feel like this may be bad practice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the `return type` of your API endpoint

```
[HttpGet("users")]
public List<User> getAllUsers(){

  List<User> userList = new List<User>;
  
  ...code for adding persons and businesses to userList...

  return Ok(userList);
  
}
```

Comment: You're right I forgot, edited it now. However this doesn't change the result. y or z are still not received client-side. I think it might be something about how C# serializes classes implementing a interface?